# removig items from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

In an ArrayList, I have the same kind of objects. Each object has an id, name, and number as their fields. There is a chance that more than one object will have the same phone number. How can I make the ArrayList in such a way that all the ArrayList objects have distinct phone numbers?

Comment: Let's say you have `objA` and `objB` with the same phone-number. `objA` is added to the `ArrayList`, then `objB` "wants" to be added to the `ArrayList` too. What would happen with `objB`? It would just don't be "accepted" *(added)*? Just curiosity.

Comment: But then there will be two objects with the same `phone-number` in the `ArrayList`. I think that's not what you expected.

Comment: In some cases, I need those two objects.

Answer (score 1):

override in your class methods `equals()` and `hashCode()`. In equals you will compare by phone number. Generate hashcode from your phone number too.

Now you are ready to use `Set` interface which will compare your objects by phone numbers automatically and exclude duplicates.

example below:

```
public class Test {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;

    public Test(int id, String name, String phoneNumber) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Test test = (Test) o;
        return phoneNumber.equals(test.phoneNumber);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return phoneNumber.hashCode();
    }
}
```

now instead of using `List<Test> arr = ArrayList<Test>()`, use `Set<Test> mySet = new HashSet<Test>()`.

Comment: `hashCode()` is only handy in case of `HashSet`, otherwise I feel `equals()` should be enough

Answer (score 0):

Try [Set.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

A collection that contains no duplicate elements.

Comment: Use arraylist.contain("number") distinct objects

Comment: @jay That won't work, since the objects in `ArrayList` are objects, not numbers alone.

Comment: I know but you can use like this : if(!list.get(0).containsValue(number)); where 0 will be your index when you add object to arraylist

Answer (score 0):

First solution that comes to my mind is to use a `HashMap`.

Simply create a HashMap with the 'phonenumber' as key and your object as the value. After adding all the elements, you will have the list of objects with unique phone numbers. Simply iterate over this to create the List that you need.